# How to locate code called by .External2()?

Tags: r

I would like to learn how `optim(..., hessian=TRUE)` computes a Hessian, so I took a look at the function's definition. Near its end, it includes this call to `.External2()`:

```
if (hessian) 
    res$hessian <- .External2(C_optimhess, res$par, fn1, 
        gr1, con)
```

Looks like there's a call to an external C function named `C_optimhess`, so I `grep`'d the R source directory for `C_optimhess`, but came up emptyhanded. There are only two occurrences of that string in R's code base, one in `optim` and one in `optimHess`. Both functions are defined in `$R_SOURCE_DIR/src/library/stats/R/optim.R`, and that file includes no additional hints/comments/references.

`optim`'s help file references code on which several of the function's optimization methods were based, but doesn't (seem to) point to the source of `C_optimhess`.

In a case like this, where should I look to find the C code being called by `.External2`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Notice that `C_optimhess` is an object, not a string.

```
> stats:::C_optimhess
$name
[1] "optimhess"

$address
<pointer: 0x266b1a0>
attr(,"class")
[1] "RegisteredNativeSymbol"

$dll
DLL name: stats
Filename: /usr/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so
Dynamic lookup: FALSE

$numParameters
[1] 4

attr(,"class")
[1] "ExternalRoutine"  "NativeSymbolInfo"
```

So you need to grep for "optimhess" in `$R_SOURCE_DIR/src/library/stats/src/`:

```
josh@compy: $R_SOURCE_DIR/src/library/stats/src
> grep optimhess *
init.c:    EXTDEF(optimhess, 4),
optim.c:SEXP optimhess(SEXP call, SEXP op, SEXP args, SEXP rho)
statsR.h:SEXP optimhess(SEXP call, SEXP op, SEXP args, SEXP rho);
```

Comment: Great, thanks! (A line or two about this might make a nice addition to the "Functions that call compiled code" section of [your increasingly comprehensive answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function/19226817#19226817).)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: done; and it's finally community wiki, as it should have been from the beginning (but I wasn't allowed to mark it as CW).

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: Your answer does not work for me: I dont have a `$R_SOURCE_DIR` defined. Also, `find *src*` in `R.home()` and in `dirname $(which R)` does not return any source code file or directory. How can I find the source code?

Comment: @Chris: `$R_SOURCE_DIR` isn't an actual environment variable. It's the location where you downloaded the R sources.  Most R installs do not include the sources, so you need to get them yourself. You can get a [daily snapshot of R-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/R/daily/) or clone [Winston's copy on GitHub](https://github.com/wch/r-source/)