# Source code of nlm function in stats package

Tags: r, nlm

I need to find the source code of the nlm function.

When I use

```
edit(nlm)
```

below code appears

```
function (f, p, ..., hessian = FALSE, typsize = rep(1, length(p)), 
    fscale = 1, print.level = 0, ndigit = 12, gradtol = 1e-06, 
    stepmax = max(1000 * sqrt(sum((p/typsize)^2)), 1000), steptol = 1e-06, 
    iterlim = 100, check.analyticals = TRUE) 
{
    print.level <- as.integer(print.level)
    if (print.level < 0 || print.level > 2) 
        stop("'print.level' must be in {0,1,2}")
    msg <- (1 + c(8, 0, 16))[1 + print.level]
    if (!check.analyticals) 
        msg <- msg + (2 + 4)
    .External2(C_nlm, function(x) f(x, ...), p, hessian, typsize, 
        fscale, msg, ndigit, gradtol, stepmax, steptol, iterlim)
}
```

now when I want to see what is insode `C_nlm`

I tried

```
stats:::C_nlm
```

and I get

```
$name
[1] "nlm"

$address
<pointer: 0x0000000004a83920>
attr(,"class")
[1] "RegisteredNativeSymbol"

$dll
DLL name: stats
Filename: C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.2/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll
Dynamic lookup: FALSE

$numParameters
[1] 11

attr(,"class")
[1] "ExternalRoutine"  "NativeSymbolInfo"
```

After some web search I found out that I need to use `grep` after this.

But I am not getting how to use it.
I tried these references

[How to locate code called by .External2()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665492/how-to-locate-code-called-by-external2)

[How can I view the source code for a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function/19226817#19226817)

Can anyone please tell me how to proceed further?

Comment: @iShouldUseAName Windows 8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can browse the R source code at this GitHub repo: [r-source](https://github.com/wch/r-source).

Search it for the term "SEXP nlm" since `stats:::C_nlm` points to a function with the name `"nlm"` and all functions returning data to R use a datatype called `SEXP` (S expression).

You'll get two hits in the files [statsR.h](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/src/statsR.h) and [optimize.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/src/optimize.c). The c-file is what you are looking for, so go down to the line starting with `SEXP nlm` and you got it.

```
SEXP nlm(SEXP call, SEXP op, SEXP args, SEXP rho)
{
    SEXP value, names, v, R_gradientSymbol, R_hessianSymbol;

    double *x, *typsiz, fscale, gradtl, stepmx,
    steptol, *xpls, *gpls, fpls, *a, *wrk, dlt;

    int code, i, j, k, itnlim, method, iexp, omsg, msg,
    n, ndigit, iagflg, iahflg, want_hessian, itncnt;


/* .Internal(
 *  nlm(function(x) f(x, ...), p, hessian, typsize, fscale,
 *      msg, ndigit, gradtol, stepmax, steptol, iterlim)
 */
    function_info *state;
```